# iOS diff in days using dateComponent(_:from:to:) - what does nil mean for the result day?

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I'm calculating the diff between two `Date`s:

```swift
let diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: oldDate, to newDate)
```

and I got a `DateComponents` as a result, in which the `day` property is an optional, the doc doesn't say it's guaranteed to have a non-nil `day` in this calculation, so I wonder if I can make the assumption that `day` will never be `nil` in this case, even if the two `Date` are the same, `day` should be 0 instead of `nil`; Or, is it possible to have a `day` which equals to `nil`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the contract for the function call is ambiguous. A `DateComponent`'s properties are **all** optional. It seems like it should return a value in the `days` property when that's what you ask for, but I'd still code defensively.

I call the force-cast operator the "crash if nil" operator, because that's what it does.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, would it be even better if we explicitly check for `nil` and do a `preconditionFailure` with a proper message so that we see a bit more information during testing?